# I want to re-open the camera view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I opened the camera view using UIImagePickerController
After taking a picture, I created a modal view again to process this picture

When I closed the picture processing modal view
the camera view shows again. 
But it doesn't work. The camera view is closed so I can't use the camera again 
In order to re-use the camera, I have to close the broken camera view.
I don't want to do that.

I want to re-open the camera after the picture processing modal view closed.

How can I implement?

Here is the first camera delegate code

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    .......

    UIImagePickerController* cp = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cp.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    cp.delegate = cameraDelegate;
    cp.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cp.showsCameraControls = NO;

    [picker presentModalViewController:cameraPicker animated:YES];
    .........
}
```

Here is the second camera delegate source

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
     // processing and saving images
}
```

here is the delegate code when I touched "cancel"

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
      NSLog(@"Second Camera closed.");

      // ... release resources

      [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
      [self release];

 }
```

I opened the camera and I opened the camera again after the first camera takes picture
When I touched the cancel button on the second camera modal view,  
the first camera modal view appears but it is closed.

I tried to solve it but I couldn't. 
So I implemented that if I touched the "cancel" button, the two model views is closed
at the same time.
but I want to solve that problem

Comment: Can you provide the source code of your `UIImagePickerController`'s delegate?

Comment: Thanks. I add some source code. I want to load two camera modal view. After I touched the "take picture" button on the first camera view, the second camera view appears. After I touched "cancel" button on the second view, the second modal view disappears and the first camera modal view appear. But there is just black view like a closed shutter.

Comment: you can't present two cameraPicker modally at the same time. You should present one, dismiss it and then present a second one. Why do you need two at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

When you dismiss the first picker you have to do it without animation:

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

in this way you can instantly reopen another picker without any problem.